# Given piecewise CDF function to find MLE of parameters

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

> A collection of independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are modelled with a common
>   distribution denoted by
>   $$P(X_i \le x)=\begin{cases}
> 0, \text{if }x<0 \\
> (x/\beta)^\alpha, \text{if }0\le x \le \beta \\
> 1, \text{if }x>\beta
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   for fixed positive parameters $\alpha, \beta$.
>   Find the PDF of $X_i$ and MLEs of $\alpha,\beta.$

**What I have done**

I took first order derivative of the piecewise function and get
$$ f(x)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\left(\frac{x}{\beta}\right)^{\alpha-1},\text{ for }0\le x\le \beta.
$$
Then I calculate the log-likelihood function and get
$$ l(\alpha,\beta)=n \log(\alpha)-n \log(\beta)-(n\alpha-n)\log(\beta)+(\alpha-1)\sum_{i}\log(X_i).
$$
But then I solve for $\alpha$ and get $\alpha = 0,$ I don't know where is going wrong.

Comment: Solved $\alpha$ from what? Did you differentiate the log-likelihood? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/374396/119261.

Comment: You can get the proper font for $\log$ by using `\log`. For other operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: The question has already been answered at the post linked to above. If you want to know what went wrong in your own calculations, you need to show more of them. What did you solve for $\alpha$, and how did you get $\alpha=0$?